# FFmpeg and Ruby linkage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed encoding. Errors: no output file created. Full output: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
 Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
 Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libogg.0.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

I've installed ffmpeg through brew, and installed both the 'ffmpeg' gem and the 'streamio-ffmpeg' gem.

Running:

```
otool -L /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
```

gives me this output:

```
/usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

The file I'm using ffmpeg in, looks like this:

```
# lib/carrierwave/ffmpeg.rb
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
module CarrierWave
  module FFMPEG
    module ClassMethods
      def resample( bitrate )
        process :resample => bitrate
      end
    end

    def resample( bitrate )
      directory = File.dirname( current_path )
      tmpfile   = File.join( directory, "tmpfile" )

      FileUtils.mv( current_path, tmpfile )

      file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)
      file.transcode( current_path, :audio_bitrate => bitrate)

      File.delete( tmpfile )
    end
  end
end
```